# Windows XP Mode won't start in WIn7 64 bit. Server Execution failed

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-xp-mode

I am using Win7, without SP1 yet, and trying to run Windows Virtual PC.  My pc works fine with VMWare Workstation, and the BIOS has hardware virtualization enabled.  The MS tool that detects hardware virtualization support says it's fine.

When I run XP Mode, after install I get this error:

```
Windows Virtual PC

Cannot start Windows Virtual PC Host Process. Check the System event log for more details

Server execution failed

[OK]
```

The system event log has only one recent error, that happened right when XP mode starts:

```
The server {9A1774B7-8251-4468-A214-61DCAED9AC2F} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

my initial Google-foo points to this error happening when running VirtualPC inside another VM tool like VMware.  I am NOT doing that.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have VPC 2007 sp1 or the initial release?

Comment: Are you running VMWare at the same time as trying to run Virtual PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VirtualPC "XP Mode" image was corrupt.  In fact, my whole system was corrupt. Reformatted and reinstalled entire system, and reinstalled XP mode, and problems went away.